# JavaScript scope issue with this.connection

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the below JavaScript code.  In the function update, the `this.connection` resolves to undefined instead of a number.  What am I doing wrong?

```
function Net()
{
    this.connection = -1;    
    this.counter = 1;
    this.timelastsend = -1;
    setInterval( this.update, 3000);
}

Net.prototype.update = function()
{          
    if (this.connection > 0 && this.timelastsend > 0)
    {
        var now = new Date().valueOf();        
        if (now - this.timelastsend > 1000 * 60)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does this.timelastsend also get resolved to undefined?

Comment: how are you calling the update function?

Comment: How do you instantiate the Net object and how do you call the update function? As much as i can see if this is done properly it should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the problems of using `this` is that `this` is dependent on the way you call the function.

`setInterval` will call your `update` method as if it were a standalone function, and so `this` will be set to the global object.

If you really need to use the `this` functionality, rewrite your call to to setInterval as follows:

```
function Net() {
    var self = this;
    this.connection = -1;    
    this.counter = 1;
    this.timelastsend = -1;
    setInterval( function () { self.update() }, 3000);
}
```

This way, you’ll create a `self` variable which will keep referring to your object (*if* you’ve created it using the `new` operator — another reason to avoid `this`).

---

**Addendum:**
If you’re not actively descending lots of objects from your Net pseudoclass, I’d refactor the thing as follows:

```
function createNet() {
    var connection = -1,
        counter = -1,
        timelastsent = -1,
        self,
        update;

    update = function () {
        var now;
        if (connection > 0 && timelastsent > 0) {
            now = new Date().valueOf();
            if (now - timelastsent > 1000 * 60) {

                // ... update code ...

                counter += 1;
                timelastsent = now;
            }
        }
    };

    setInterval(update, 3000);

    return {
        update: update,
        getTimeLastSent: function () { return timelastsent; },
        getCounter: function () { return counter; },
        getConnection: function () { return connection; }
    };
}
```

You’ll notice there is no mention of `this` anywhere, which means no ambiguity.  I’ve included three getters for the connection, counter and timelastsent properties, but if you want those to be writable from outside the object, you could just as easily add them to the created object.